# Is there a way to save an int 3d array as the value of a hashtable in C#?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, hashtable

I'm trying to create a C# application that simulates a car park used by customers in events.

So far, I've created an int 3d array which holds some information about the car park. What I want to achieve, is the creation of a hashtable, which will have a unique id as the key(the id of the customer) and the 3d array as the value.

```cpp
int[][][] myArray = new int[10][][];

... //Code that populates the 3d array

Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();

ht.Add(1, myArray[0][0][0]); // myArray[0][0][0] has the value of [3][5][7]
// When debugging the hashtable the key is 1 and value 1
```

What I'm expecting when I access the hashtable with the id 1 is the 3d array and not the number 1 that is currently returning.

If what I'm asking is not feasible, please suggest another solution for accessing a 3d array based on a unique key. Thank you in advance.

Comment: use classes? pocos? named tuples? use _typed_ Hastables from System.Collections.Generic ? post a [mcve] instead of incomplete code? You would need to add and `int[3]` to your hashmap - currently you are adding only a single `int` to it ... `myArray[0][0][0]` is an int - not an `int[3]`

Comment: Use a Dictionary<int, int[][][]> instead of HashTable

Answer (score -1):

Instead of:

```
ht.Add(1, myArray[0][0][0]);
```

...try:

```
ht.Add(1, myArray);
```

But you should prefer a Dictionary because it is strongly typed and protects you from run-time errors.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, int[][][]>();
```